# Using Spring Boot Data to read MySQL data

Tags: mysql, spring, groovy

I'm trying to create a framework to read data from MySQL using Spring Data. The end goal is to be able to write automated tests that could read data from two different MySQL dbs and compare the data (for example, to make sure data is replicating correctly). I'm currently having loads of trouble in actually getting the Spring code to work (I've never used Spring before, I've tried modifying some various tutorial code I've found on the web, but so far haven't gotten it working.)

Here's what I've got.

MySQL
table: credentials
columns: id (int), password_hash (string)
Has 4 entries in it.

Project layout:

```
src/main
  groovy
    domain
      Credentials
    repository
      CredentialsRepository
  resources
    application.properties
src/test/groovy/
  CredentialsTest
```

---

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-accessing-data-jpa'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.4.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.4.3.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
```

---

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db
spring.datasource.username=my_user
spring.datasource.password=my_password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

---

Credentials.groovy

```
package domain

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id

import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = 'credentials')
class Credentials {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(name='id')
    int id

    @Column(name='password_hash')
    String passwordHash

    protected Credentials() {}

    @Override
    String toString() {
        "Credential: [id=${id}, passwordHash=${passwordHash}]"
    }
}
```

---

CredentialsRepository.groovy

```
package repository

import domain.Credentials
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface CredentialsRepository extends CrudRepository<Credentials, Integer> {
}
```

---

CredentialsTest.groovy

```
import domain.Credentials
import repository.CredentialsRepository
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) //@EnableJpaRepositories(['domain.Credentials'])
@SpringBootTest(classes = MysqlJpaDemoApplication.class)
class CredentialsTest {
    @Autowired
    CredentialsRepository credentialsRepository

    @Test
    void testLoadCredentials() {
        List<Credentials> credentialsList = credentialsRepository.findAll() as ArrayList<Credentials>
        assertEquals(20, credentialsList.size())
    }
}
```

Running the testLoadCredentials test gives the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'CredentialsTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'credentialsRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.CredentialsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.CredentialsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 33 more

2016-12-28 14:14:32.638  INFO 39748 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@742ff096: startup date [Wed Dec 28 14:14:32 PST 2016]; root of context hierarchy

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: Some things I've tried:

* Add `@Repository` to the CredentialsRepository interface
* Add `@EnableJpaRepositories(['domain.Credentials'])` to the CredentialsTest class
* Use `@SpringBootApplication` on an Application class with a main method

None of those worked for me.

Comment: This works: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/.  The problem is probably due to JUnit not wiring the beans appropriately.

Comment: I was using that tutorial earlier but couldn't get it to work. If I use this code: I get an error that the symbol args can't be resolved. If I remove the args part like this:

        @Bean
        CommandLineRunner demo(CredentialsRepository repository) {

                log.info("I'm doing stuff!")
                for (Credentials cred : repository) {
                    log.info(cred.toString())
                }

        }

I get: `No qualifying bean of type 'repository.CredentialsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.`

Comment: Couldn't get it to work?  I have.  You're doing it wrong.  I recommend not using Spring bean factory for unit tests.

Comment: Try enabling auto scanning for the repository package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what got it to work:

```
com.example/
  domain/
    Credentials
  repository/
    CredentialsRepository
  SpringConfig
```

---

Credentials.groovy

```
@Entity
@Table(name = 'credentials')
class Credentials {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id

    @Column(name='password_hash')
    String passwordHash

    protected Credentials() {}

    @Override
    String toString() {
        "Credential: [id=${id}, passwordHash=${passwordHash}]"
    }
}
```

---

CredentialsRepository

```
interface CredentialsRepository extends CrudRepository<Credentials, Integer> {}
```

---

SpringConfig.groovy

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan('com.example')
class SpringConfig {}
```

---

CredentialsTest.groovy

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=SpringConfig.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringConfig.class)
class CredentialsTest {

    @Autowired
    CredentialsRepository credentialsRepository

    @Test
    void testLoadCredentials() {
        List<Credentials> credentialsList = credentialsRepository.findAll() as ArrayList<Credentials>
        assertEquals(4, credentialsList.size())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the application class `MysqlJpaDemoApplication` that you're using to configure your tests is in the default (top-level) package. As Spring runs some checks when using `@ComponentScan`, it will prevent your application to scan the whole classpath.

You should move `MysqlJpaDemoApplication` to a new package, ie,`com.example`. Your source folder would look like this:

```
src/main
  /groovy/com/example
  |-- /domain
  |   |-- Credentials.groovy
  |-- /repository
  |   |-- CredentialsRepository.groovy
  |-- MysqlJpaDemoApplicatin.groovy
```